# Condicionales y Ciclos en java

Tags: java, condiciones, bucles

Tengo un codigo asi:

```
for(){
   for(){
         if(){
              break;
              }

   }
}
```

Cuando le doy a ejecutar, ese break solo me saca del condicional y de un solo ciclo; ¿Como deberia hacer para que me saque del condicional y de los dos ciclos?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Devuelve un valor o setea un boolean que puedas comprobar. Un `if` en el primer bucle para mirar si ese valor está correcto o el flag se ha puesto en true, y si es así haces otro break. No sé, la verdad. Hay muchas cosas que se pueden hacer para interrumpir el flujo, podrías incluso lanzar una excepción. La estructura que mencionas es demasiado escueta, pero en principio seteando un flag a true puedes comprobarlo en el primer for antes de hacer nada. Otra opción es moverlo a una función y salirte con un `return`, que es lo que haría yo supongo.

Comment: Hola gotaluism, podrias decir si las respuestas te fueron utilies, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean stop = false;

for ()
{
   if (stop)
   {
      break;
   }

   for ()
   {
      if ()
      {
         stop = true;
         break;
      }    
   }
}
```

Se declara la **variable booleana stop** y se inicializa en **false**. Cuando en el **ciclo for interno** se cumple la condición entonces esta variable toma el valor de **true** y se ejecuta la **instrucción break** del **ciclo for interno**. Al salir del **ciclo for interno** se cae en las iteraciones del **ciclo for externo** y es aquí donde se pregunta si la **variable stop** tiene el valor de **true**, de tenerlo entonces se ejecuta la **instrucción break** y se sale del **ciclo for externo**, terminando así la ejecución de ambos **ciclos for**.

Answer (score 0):

En Java puedes usar `break` con etiquetas. Un ejemplo:

```
outerloop:
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < 5; j++) {
        if (i * j > 6) {
            System.out.println("Breaking");
            break outerloop;
         }
         System.out.println(i + " " + j);
    }
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

Imprime:

```
0 0
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
1 0
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
Breaking
Done
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/886979/13419694